# Ruby RestClient converts XML to Hash

Tags: ruby, rest

I need to send a POST request as an XML string but I get odd results. The code:

```
require 'rest_client'

response = RestClient.post "http://127.0.0.1:2000", "<tag1>text</tag1>", :content_type => "text/xml"
```

I expect to receive `"<tag1>text</tag1>"` as the parameter on the request server. Instead, I get `"tag1"=>"text"`. It converts the XML to a hash. Why is that? Any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
response = RestClient.post "http://127.0.0.1:2000", 
                           "<tag1>text</tag1>", 
                           {:accept => :xml, :content_type => :xml}
```

I think you just needed to specify the ":accept" to let it know you wanted to receive it in the XML format. Assuming it's your own server, you can debug on the server and see the request format used is probably html.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm doing something similar to above in my current project and it works as I expect. Here's exactly what I'm sending: "response = RestClient.post(my_url, xml_body, {:content_type => :xml, :accept => :json, :cookies => @login_cookies}). The response.body is a string of JSON results from the server. I was previously sending an :accept => :xml and getting the string XML result back. As for sending the xml_body you might need to send the "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" xml header. I may just not understand the problem because I think I'm doing exactly what your talking about.

Comment: Rails will try to interpret the XML body as a resource/model on the server. If you don't want that, then try sending the XML as a param variable like ':xml_data => "<tag1>text</tag1>"', then it's just treated as an escaped string and will remain a string on the server.

Comment: I can't send it as a param variable either because I'm trying to send it to a third party service that needs it to be plain XML.

Comment: In that case you might be better off using more direct HTTP sending. RestClient seems to be oriented towards RESTful resource manipulation. If you are sending it to a non-RESTful URL, then it might be easier using something else.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using RestClient, use Ruby's built-in [Open::URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/) for `GET` requests or something like [Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) or the incredibly powerful [Typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus):

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => 'ruby', 'max' => '50')
```

In Typhoeus, you'd use:

```
res = Typhoeus::Request.post(
  'http://localhost:3000/posts',
  :params => {
    :title   => 'test post',
    :content => 'this is my test'
  }
)
```

Your resulting page, if it's in XML will be easy to parse using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org):

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(res.body)
```

At that point you'll have a fully parsed DOM, ready to be searched, using Nokogiri's search methods, such as `search` and `at`, or any of their related methods.